# Why "sudo perl" and "perl" execute different perl version?

Tags: perl, ubuntu, perlbrew

Ubuntu 14 came with `perl v5.18.2`, but I would like to test my program with `perl v5.22.0` which is installed through `perlbrew` and then `perlbrew switch perl-5.22.0` to use the version I want.

After switch to `perl v5.22.0`, I have tried to test my program with `sudo` but why it is executed in default `perl v5.18.2`?

> `perl -v`: result
>   [image]
>
> `sudo perl -v` : result
>   [image]

Comment: Can you report the output of `which perl` and `sudo which perl`?

Comment: http://gugod.org/2010/12/a-shared-perlbrew-root-for-multiple-users/

Comment: @SebastianRedl `which perl` results `/home/xxxx/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.0/bin/perl` and `sudo which perl` is `/usr/bin/perl`. How can I force to use `perl v5.22.0` for both `perl` and `sudo perl`?

Comment: You want: `sudo \`which perl\` -v`

Comment: @s_m The easiest way to do that is to not rely on 'perl' as a command-line alias for /usr/bin/perl (or anything else) and use absolute paths. So do `sudo /home/xxx/....../bin/perl -v` and it won't look in root's path for which version of perl to use, it will use the version you explicitly specified, using it's absolute path.